# Is there a way to see a visual of the css hex in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I love using Paletton for my color Schemes and I also like generic names in case I decide to change the entire theme. My CSS looks like this:

```
.background-color-primary-0 { background-color: #FE6003 }   /* Orange Primary background-color */
.background-color-primary-1 { background-color: #FF9C61 }
.background-color-primary-2 { background-color: #FF833A }
.background-color-primary-3 { background-color: #CC4C00 }
.background-color-primary-4 { background-color: #A83E00 }
```

Does anyone know if I can highlight the hex and see a visual of the color within the editor.

Also, is the drop down list you see when typing a background property in a css class editable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke code completion for color property value, it shows also all already used colors in CSS file and the code completion contains always colored square and hex code.

CSS completion for background is not editable, editor only learns used colors in css file and offers them along with default set of colors.